# LOB Desktop applications using HTML5, CSS, Node.js, Chromium Embedded Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, css, chromium-embedded

With the tremendous progress going on with web technologies, does it make sense to bring these to desktop and client-server applications.

We typically build our applications using winforms and wpf and the code base is like 100k+ lines of code.

Is it worth exploring the option of HTML5 UI and Node.js backend and use a framework like the chromium embedded framework or node-webkit.

The reason I am asking this is that the support from Microsoft for the desktop technologies is questionable (wpf, metro apps ...).

At least with the technologies I listed, it is easy to port to make the application work across all platforms and companies like microsoft and google are pushing for html5 and javascript.

Comment: Depends on what your application does. If it is a fairly standard CRUD app I would say yes. But, if you're doing 3d graphics manipulation or some other processor/memory/disk intensive task I would say no.

Comment: Basically I want to use the UI power of HTML5 and CSS instead of technologies like wpf/metro apps. I could use a websocket server written in c# or C++ as my backend too. Does it make sense to try these?

Answer (score 0):

A number of companies are using CEF and similar web-based technologies for desktop applications.

- Steam from Valve is CEF based (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework), as is
- Spotify https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-Windows/Chromium-Embedded-Framework/td-p/912377 and
- Adobe Creative Cloud (I believe using Adobe Brackets Shell over CEF and incorporating Node.js) https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell

Advantages for them are that server side content can be delivered to the application, as can UI updates, and the client machine is fully accessible.

We are using it for product authorization and delivery, the advantages of CEF for us are dynamic update from the server of both UI and business logic in Javascript, and because CEF allows calls from Javascript to C++, we can access files on disk and Registry entries that pure Web code cannot.

So I would recommend looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

For ordinary Line Of Business applications, I would suggest no, don't go half-way.

I used to do advanced UI development in WPF, and it was amazing for its time (a decade ago), but nowadays it is really amazing what can be done all within a modern web browser. And yes, Microsoft's support of full-powered desktop technologies is like a ghost town (I suspect they just want to get their 30% commission on apps in their store, so they've shifted focus to UWP).

Why do you need to create a hybrid desktop/web application?  Unless you have a specific (and important) need to break out of the browser's sandbox, why not go all the way and create a web application?  Modern browsers have a lot more capabilities now, and they keep getting better.

There are also many technologies and frameworks that really help to make large-scale web application development a lot easier than it used to be.